# Rails How To Upload Code To The Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I managed to create my first ROR application, called myapp, locally and I also have created another ROR application on my webfaction server with the same name myapp. My question  is every time I run commands "rails generate model" or "rails generate controller", how can I synchronise my local environment with my webfaction server. There seem to be lots of files generated when you run rails commands. Does it mean I have to upload the whole application directory every time I generate something? Kindly suggest with your experience, I'm very new to Rails.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would go for [Heroku](http://heroku.com) first. It's free and easy and along the way you will learn some about hosting Rails apps.

Getting started with Heroku is a good place to go first https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will definitely give it a try now. If you have good materials, please recommend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is indeed the easy way out, if you are looking into more "metal" deployment - use [Capistrano](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano)

Comment: thanks for suggesting. I'm actually trying to use capistrano now.